# How to set filter for value 'Today' in Invoice.Payments.search.view and invoice.order.search.view in odoo 9?

Tags: view, filter, odoo-9

I am new in Odoo-9 system, please help me to set filter with value 'Today' in Invoice.Payments.search.view and invoice.order.search.view in odoo 9. And are there diferent about structure if the filter value is 'yesterday'